# Different NavigationDrawer items for Different activities in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, navigation-drawer

Here i am using NavigationDrawer for my activities.It is working fine.i am using Recyclerview for displaying NavigationDrawer items. Now i want to display different NavigationDrawer Item for different Activity..Here i am using nav_drawer_labels in FragmentDrawer to display items.How to display nav_drawer_labels1 in another activity.I mean i have to display different NavigationDrawer  in each activity..here is my code.

**CompProfileDisplay.java**

```
public class CompProfileDisplay extends AppCompatActivity implements  OnItemClickListener, FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {

    private static String TAG = CompProfileDisplay.class.getSimpleName();

    private MenuItem menuitems;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment1;
    private ImageView img;

    private int count;
    private TextView textView;
    private String doc;
    public static final String UPLOAD_URL = "http://website.com/aboutme_update.php";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        setContentView(R.layout.compprofile_display);
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView10);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        final Context context = this;


        drawerFragment1 = (FragmentDrawer)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment1.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
        drawerFragment1.setDrawerListener(this);

        // display the second navigation drawer view on app launch
        displayView(0);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(ProfileLogin.SHARED_PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences1 = getSharedPreferences(ClickToComp.SHARED_PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);


        img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);//no title in dialog.
                dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable( new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.im);

                Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset( getAssets(), "fontawesome-webfont.ttf" );
                TextView txt = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.custom_fullimage_placename);
                txt.setTypeface(font);

                String url1 = "http://www.website.com/" + doc;
                new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.fullimage))
                        .execute(url1);


                //on click of cancel icon/btn popup screen will close.
                txt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }

                });
                dialog.show();
            }
        });

    }
    private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                            long id) {

        Intent intent;
        switch (position) {
            default:
                intent = new Intent(CompProfileDisplay.this, Banking.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.testAction);
        menuItem.setIcon(buildCounterDrawable(count, R.drawable.add));

        return true;

    }


    private Drawable buildCounterDrawable(int count, int backgroundImageId) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.action_bar_notifitcation_icon, null);
        view.setBackgroundResource(backgroundImageId);

        if (count == 0) {
            View counterTextPanel = view.findViewById(R.id.counterValuePanel);
            counterTextPanel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.count);
            textView.setText("" + count);
            textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(CompProfileDisplay.this, "You have new friend request", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }

        view.measure(
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());

        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        view.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        return new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();



        if (id == R.id.testAction) {
            if(count>0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have new friend request", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You dont have any new notification", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return true;
        }


        if(id == R.id.action_search){
             /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), vault_no, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;*/
            //logout();
        }


        if(id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position) {
        displayView(position);
    }

    private void displayView(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                /*fragment = new HomeFragment();*/
                title = "Profile";
                break;

            case 1:
                /*fragment = new ProfileFragment();
                title = getString(R.string.title_profile);
                break;*/
                startActivity(new Intent(this, CompProfileDisplay.class));
                return;
            case 2:

                startActivity(new Intent (this,DisplayContact.class));
                return;
            case 3:

                startActivity(new Intent(this, DocUpload.class));
                return;

            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

            // set the toolbar title
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        }
    }

}
```

**FragmentDrawer.class**

```
public class FragmentDrawer extends Fragment {

    private static String TAG = FragmentDrawer.class.getSimpleName();

    public static final String SHARED_PREF_NAME = "myloginapp";
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private  String doc;
    private String fullname;
    private String vault;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private NavigationDrawerAdapter adapter;
    private View containerView;
    private static String[] titles = null;
    private FragmentDrawerListener drawerListener;

    public FragmentDrawer() {

    }

    public void setDrawerListener(FragmentDrawerListener listener) {
        this.drawerListener = listener;
    }

    public static List<NavDrawerItem> getData() {
        List<NavDrawerItem> data = new ArrayList<>();


        // preparing navigation drawer items
        for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
            NavDrawerItem navItem = new NavDrawerItem();
            navItem.setTitle(titles[i]);
            data.add(navItem);
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // here i am displaying nav_drawer_labels items in one activity.
        titles = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_labels);
//i want to display nav_drawer_labels1 in another activity.
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflating view layout
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        ImageView img = (ImageView)layout.findViewById(R.id.img);

        TextView name = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView vault_no = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.vault);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences1 = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(FragmentDrawer.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        vault = sharedPreferences1.getString(ProfileLogin.EMAIL_SHARED_PREF,"Not Available");

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =  this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(FragmentDrawer.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        doc = sharedPreferences.getString(ClickToLogin.DOC_SHARED_PREF,"Not Available");
        fullname = sharedPreferences.getString(ClickToLogin.FULLNAME_SHARED_PREF,"Not Available");

        name.setText(fullname);
        vault_no.setText(vault);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
        String url1 = "http://www.miisky.com/"+doc;
        new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.img))
                .execute(url1);


        adapter = new NavigationDrawerAdapter(getActivity(), getData());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), recyclerView, new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                drawerListener.onDrawerItemSelected(view, position);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(containerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

            }
        }));

        return layout;
    }

    private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }

    public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, final Toolbar toolbar) {
        containerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
                toolbar.setAlpha(1 - slideOffset / 2);
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

    }

    public static interface ClickListener {
        public void onClick(View view, int position);

        public void onLongClick(View view, int position);
    }

    static class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

        private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
        private ClickListener clickListener;

        public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener) {
            this.clickListener = clickListener;
            gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                    View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                    if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                        clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

            View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
                clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

        }

    }

    public interface FragmentDrawerListener {
        public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position);
    }
}
```

**string.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

 <string name="nav_item_home1">Home</string>
    <string name="nav_item_profile1">Profile</string>
    <string name="nav_item_customersupport">Customer Support</string>
    <string name="nav_item_dealer">Dealer Network</string>

    <string-array name="nav_drawer_labels1">
        <item>@string/nav_item_home1</item>
        <item>@string/nav_item_profile1</item>
        <item>@string/nav_item_customersupport</item>

    </string-array>

 <string name="nav_item_home">Home</string>
    <string name="nav_item_profile">Profile</string>
    <string name="nav_item_contacts">Contacts</string>
    <string name="nav_item_docupload">Upload Documents</string>

    <!-- navigation drawer item labels  -->
    <string-array name="nav_drawer_labels">
        <item>@string/nav_item_home</item>
        <item>@string/nav_item_profile</item>
        <item>@string/nav_item_contacts</item>

    </string-array>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Navigation drawer is meant to be used with fragments.

The main activity host the the nav drawer.

Fragments make it easy to swap the drawer content a keep its state.

If you wanted to use acitvity instead then you should create a base activity conaining the drawer so that all your activities inherit from that activity.

This way the nav drawer can persist from activity to activity.

Comment: so that base activity woulde be similar like my other activity with different nav drawer..?

Comment: @sunily please implement this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/19451842/1880431

Comment: ok i will look into that..but i want different navigation drawer..i mean different nav drawer items in two of my activities..?is that link will solve my requirement..?bcs i am using activities instead of fragments..

Comment: @sunily yes it will solve it, if not then tweak it to fit your requirements

Comment: @meda..can u able to see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39268248/upload-email-id-along-with-name-and-phone-number-in-android)..?can u able to help with this one..